# Criteria for the "Announcer" badge

Tags: discussion, badges

I have read the criteria for the ["Announcer" badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer), and I am not sure if I understand this correctly.

> Share a link to a question later visited by 25 unique IP addresses

The intention of the word *unique* in this criteria is to ensure that the question is visited by 25 people.  However, if 25 students in the *same* school/company visit that shared link, *no* "Announcer" badge will be awarded if [they share the same IP](http://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/sharing_the_same_ip_address).

Moreover, the *same* user may visit the shared link in *different* places in order to gain this badge.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You understood the description correctly. If one person visits  (via the link you shared) from 25 computers with different IP addresses, you get the badge. But if 25 different people visit via the link from the same IP address, you don't.

The system tracks what is practical to track.  Which makes sense because...

- It's just a badge.
- On the Internet, nobody knows you're a (dog|badge-hunter).

Comment: "On the internet nobody cares that you scream."

Comment: Exactly. If that badge came with even a modest bit of money, say $20, that would be a different story.

Comment: @David That said, there was a bit of outrage over [fraudulent Publicist badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300470/3717023) a while ago...